# Can I do conditional isset?

Tags: php, if-statement, switch-statement, isset

I'm not sure the best way to do this, so ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Basically, at the start of a PHP page, I'm trying to get a variable of $pin.

The value can be taken from different calls throughout the website.

So originally I had:

```
if (isset($Reader->Pin)) { $pin = $Reader->Pin; } else { $pin = isset($_GET['Pin']) ? $_GET['Pin'] : ''; }
```

As you can see, there are several methods of getting the PIN number throughout the site (not my code).

I need to add something in here that can also get the value of $Reader->pin (different to ->Pin!).

But at the end, if none of it matches, it still needs to come back as blank.

What's the best way I can add this in?

Comment: Your code seems fine, what do you think is missing there?

Comment: What do you want to add??

Comment: The code as it stands works, it doesn't give any errors. Apart from when somewhere in the site the PIN is referenced by $Reader->pin - at this point i get an error saying undefined variable or something. So, it means that ->Pin and ->pin are being seen as different. - Can i add something really simple next to $Reader->Pin thats like 'OR' $Reader->pin ?

Comment: Any comments, ideas or thoughts guys?

Answer (score 1):

I'd create a coalesce function and assign $pin from there:

```
function coalesce($args_)
{
    $result = null;
    if (func_num_args() > 0)
    {
        foreach(func_get_args() as $arg)
        {
            if ($arg != null)
            {
                $result = $arg;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}


// in the header:

$pin = coalesce($Reader->Pin?:null, $_GET['Pin']?:null, ..., ..., ...);
```

Now you just put the possible sources in order of importance as arguments to the coalesce function.

**edit:**

The `coalesce` function takes in any number of arguments and walks over them left to right. it returns the first argument that is not loosely null.

Comment: Can you explain what it does? The header part resembles an array type function.. Is that along the right lines?

Comment: `if (func_num_args() > 0)` is pointless. `func_get_args()` always returns array.

Comment: @machineaddict: it's not exactly pointless, While this code won't break without it, other code will and often does. I made it a habit to check if there is something to iterate over before iterating to prevent those kinds of issues while remaining consistent.

Comment: Is there a simpler way of just expanding what I've already got?

Comment: @Kris: Well, in my oppinion, you made a bad habit. While sometimes you have to check, in your case (I repeat myself again) it's pointless. Use it ONLY when necessary. Shorter code means (almost always) faster application.

Answer (score 0):

Well eventually, I worked out I could just do the following:

```
if (isset($Reader->Pin))
    { $pin = $Reader->Pin; } 
elseif (isset($Reader[0]->Pin))
    { $pin = $Reader[0]->Pin; }
else
    { $pin = isset($_GET['Pin']) ? $_GET['Pin'] : ''; }
```

Comment: I have to wait 2 days until I can mark my answer as the accepted answer? That's a bit.. wrong